# Cannot set CPU to maximum speed

Tags: ubuntu, cpu-frequency

I am trying to set all my CPUs to the maximum GHz capability. But for some reason even though the CPU is capable of 5.76GHz, when I set it to performance it only get's to 4.2GHz.

Looking at the scaling_max_freq it all set to 4.2GHz, which I guess could be the issue.

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_max_freq
4200000
```

However when I try to change it using the following method, I won't budge to anything higher.

```
echo 5700000 |tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling
```

I have also tried using cpufreq-set

```
cpufreq-set -c 0 -d 5.7GHz
```

- **OS** - Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- **Kernel** - 5.15.0-89-generic

**CPU details:**

```
    Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         48 bits physical, 48 bits vir
                         tual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  32
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-31
Vendor ID:               AuthenticAMD
  Model name:            AMD Ryzen 9 7950X3D 16-Core P
                         rocessor
    CPU family:          25
    Model:               97
    Thread(s) per core:  2
    Core(s) per socket:  16
    Socket(s):           1
    Stepping:            2
    Frequency boost:     enabled
    CPU max MHz:         5758.5928
    CPU min MHz:         3000.0000
```

UPDATE:

I can see that for some reason Ubuntu seems to think it should limit my CPU.

```
 cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/bios_limit
4200000
```

Comment: Good luck with that - 5.7 GHz is likely going to fry the L3 cache die, even with very good cooling...

Comment: *Max boost for AMD processors is the maximum frequency achievable by a **single core** on the processor **running a bursty single-threaded workload.*** - [source](https://www.amd.com/en/products/apu/amd-ryzen-9-7950x3d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you are able to determine that the BIOS does not get any good reason for limiting the frequency, in short : **YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING** :
You can have linux ignoring the bios limit.

change `/sys/module/processor/parameters/ignore_ppc` from 0 to 1.

This will be reset at next reboot, if you want to set it permanently, simply add `processor.ignore_ppc=1` to your boot command line.

Comment: tried that but doesn't seem to make any difference.